# React - Loop inputs and get sum value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sum

I am attempting to in React JS to get the sum of a group inputs, and put the sum of their total values in a div tag.

I am trying to run this event whenever a user types in any of the inputs

The problem is I am sure React has a proper way to do this!

This is my feeble attempt (please go easy - I am new to coding :)

HTML

```
<input type="number" id="comp1" name="comp1" onChange={this.handleTotal} />
<input type="number" id="comp2" name="comp2" onChange={this.handleTotal} />
<input type="number" id="comp3" name="comp3" onChange={this.handleTotal} />
<input type="number" id="comp4" name="comp4" onChange={this.handleTotal} />
<input type="number" id="comp5" name="comp5" onChange={this.handleTotal} />
<input type="number" id="comp6" name="comp6" onChange={this.handleTotal} />
<div id=total></div>
```

JS

```
handleTotal = e => {  
    // Grab all inputs that start with ID 'comp'
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="comp"]');

    // Trying to loop through the values and get the sum of all inputs
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        let totalVal = inputs[i].value
        console.log(totalVal);
    }

    //Trying to grab total values of all inputs and put in element 
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = totalVal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are not utilizing any of the React's data binding.

Best to use [React's state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) to hold the values of the `total` and all the `comp` inputs.

I've also used the [.reduce](https://alligator.io/js/finally-understand-reduce/) method in order to calculate the total for each of the input fields' values. But you can achieve the same thing with a `for` loop.

[JSFiddle: Alternative "calculateTotal" function with for loop](https://jsfiddle.net/eyrvt31k/)

[More information on Input handling in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      total: 0,
      numbers: {
        comp1: 1,
        comp2: 0,
        comp3: 4,
        comp4: 0,
        comp5: 0,
        comp6: 0
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Calculates the total after component is mounted
    this.setState({ total: this.calculateTotal(this.state.numbers) });
  }

  calculateTotal = (numbers) => {
    return Object.entries(numbers).reduce((finalValue, [key, value]) => {
      if (value === "") {
        // if entered value is empty string "", omits it
        return finalValue;
      }
      return finalValue + value;
    }, 0);
  }

  handleTotal = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target; // gets the name and value from input field
    const parsedValue = value === "" ? "" : parseFloat(value); // parses the value as a number or if empty treats it as empty string ""
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      // creates new immutable numbers object, using previous number values and the currently changed input value
      const updatedNumbers = {
        ...prevState.numbers,
        [name]: parsedValue
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names
      };
      // calculates the new total from updated numbers:
      const newTotal = this.calculateTotal(updatedNumbers);
      return {
        numbers: updatedNumbers,
        total: newTotal
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="number" name="comp1" onChange={this.handleTotal} value={this.state.numbers.comp1} />
        <input type="number" name="comp2" onChange={this.handleTotal} value={this.state.numbers.comp2}/>
        <input type="number" name="comp3" onChange={this.handleTotal} value={this.state.numbers.comp3}/>
        <input type="number" name="comp4" onChange={this.handleTotal} value={this.state.numbers.comp4}/>
        <input type="number" name="comp5" onChange={this.handleTotal} value={this.state.numbers.comp5}/>
        <input type="number" name="comp6" onChange={this.handleTotal} value={this.state.numbers.comp6}/>
        <div id="total">{this.state.total}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    let total = 0;
    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
        total += value * 1;
    }
    document.querySelector('#total').textContent = total;
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit, false);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="comp1" name="comp1" />
  <input type="number" id="comp2" name="comp2" />
  <input type="number" id="comp3" name="comp3" />
  <input type="number" id="comp4" name="comp4" />
  <input type="number" id="comp5" name="comp5" />
  <input type="number" id="comp6" name="comp6" />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<span>total</span>
<div id=total></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just re-assign variable in every iteration of a loop. Change to smth like this:

```
handleTotal = e => {  
    // Grab all inputs that start with ID 'comp'
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="comp"]');

    // Trying to loop through the values and get the sum of all inputs
    let totalVal=0
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        totalVal += inputs[i].value
        console.log(totalVal);
    }

    //Trying to grab total values of all inputs and put in element 
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = totalVal;
}
```

`+=` operator just adds value of next element to total variable. it is equal to `totalVal = totalVal  + inputs[i].value`